# Solving Second Order Differential Equations in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations

I'm having some trouble writing a program to solve second-order differential equations in Python. My issue seems to be with trying to include `t` in the `p(t)` function return, which outputs an array. If I replace the 'p' in the `dU_dx` function with the output of the `p(t)` function itself (`-2*t` in this case), it seems to work fine. Otherwise I get the error

> "setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part"

Any help figuring out how to edit my code to fix the array issue would be immensely appreciated.

This function solves the differential equation `x'' + px' + qx = 0`. Here, `q` and `p` are functions of `t`.

It is solved on the interval `[lp, rp]`.

Inputs:

- `p` is a function of `t` relating to (in front of) `x'`
- `q` is a function of `t` relating to (in front of) `x`
- `lp` is the lower time boundary
- `rp` is the upper time boundary
- `x0` is an initial `x` value
- `x0p` is an initial `x'` value
- `h` is a step size

Outputs:

- `T` is the vector of times
- `X` the approximate solution evaluated at the elements of `T`

```
def my_sode(p, q, lp, rp, x0, x0p, h):
    #You may not modify any code above this line
    
    T = arange(lp, rp + h, h)
    p = p(T)
    q = q(T)
    t = T
    def dU_dx(U, t):
        return [U[1], -(p) * U[1] - (q)*U[0]]
    U0 = [x0, x0p]
    Us = odeint(dU_dx, U0, T)
    X = Us[:,0]
    #You cannot modify anything below this line!
    return T, X
```

Using this block of code works fine.

```
def p(t): 
    return 0 

def q(t): 
    return 1 

# this is the actual solution
def sol(t):
    return sin(t) 

x0 = 0 
x0p = 1
lp = 0 
rp = pi 

Tt = linspace(lp, rp, 10)
plt.figure()
T1, X1 = my_sode(p,q, lp, rp, x0, x0p, .2)
T2, X2 = my_sode(p,q, lp, rp, x0, x0p, .1)
plt.plot(Tt, sol(Tt), 'r*', T1, X1, 'b:', T2, X2,'g')
```

This block of code produces the error.

```
def p(t): 
    return  -2 * t 

def q(t): 
    return  2 

# this is the actual solution
def sol(t):
    return t 

x0 = 0 
x0p = 1
lp = 0 
rp = 1 

Tt = linspace(lp, rp, 10)
plt.figure()
T1, X1 = my_sode(p,q, lp, rp, x0, x0p, .2)
T2, X2 = my_sode(p,q, lp, rp, x0, x0p, .1)
plt.plot(Tt, sol(Tt), 'r*', T1, X1, 'b:', T2, X2,'g')
```

Comment: In the second case, `p` returns `t`, which is an array, where in the first, it returns `0`, a number

Comment: I understand that. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps instead of setting `p = p(T)`, keep `p` the function and replace  `-(p)` with `-p(t)` inside `dU_dt`?